# Testcontainers with Podman in Java tests

Tags: testcontainers, podman, testcontainers-junit5

Is it possible to use Testcontainers with Podman in Java tests?

As of March 2022, the Testcontainers library doesn't detect an installed Podman as a valid Docker environment.

Can Podman be a Docker replacement on both MacOS with Apple silicon (local development environment) and Linux x86_64 (CI/CD environment)?

Comment: Why is this closed as "opinion-based"? The question asks "can" not "should". Voting again to reopen.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is possible to use Podman with Testcontainers in Java projects, that use Gradle on Linux and MacOS (both x86_64 and Apple silicon).

### Prerequisites

- Podman Machine and Remote Client are installed on MacOS - https://podman.io/getting-started/installation#macos
- Podman is installed on Linux - https://podman.io/getting-started/installation#linux-distributions

### Enable the Podman service

Testcontainers library communicates with Podman using socket file.

#### Linux

Start Podman service for a regular user (rootless) and make it listen to a socket:

```
systemctl --user enable --now podman.socket
```

Check the Podman service status:

```
systemctl --user status podman.socket
```

Check the socket file exists:

```
ls -la /run/user/$UID/podman/podman.sock
```

#### MacOS

Podman socket file `/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock` can be found inside the Podman-managed Linux VM. A local socket on MacOS can be forwarded to a remote socket on Podman-managed VM using SSH tunneling.

The port of the Podman-managed VM can be found with the command `podman system connection list --format=json`.

Install [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse JSON:

```
brew install jq
```

Create a shell alias to forward the local socket `/tmp/podman.sock` to the remote socket `/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock`:

```
echo "alias podman-sock=\"rm -f /tmp/podman.sock && ssh -i ~/.ssh/podman-machine-default -p \$(podman system connection list --format=json | jq '.[0].URI' | sed -E 's|.+://.+@.+:([[:digit:]]+)/.+|\1|') -L'/tmp/podman.sock:/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock' -N core@localhost\"" >> ~/.zprofile
source ~/.zprofile
```

Open an SSH tunnel:

```
podman-sock
```

Make sure the SSH tunnel is open before executing tests using Testcontainers.

### Configure Gradle build script

`build.gradle`

```
test {
    OperatingSystem os = DefaultNativePlatform.currentOperatingSystem;
    if (os.isLinux()) {
        def uid = ["id", "-u"].execute().text.trim()
        environment "DOCKER_HOST", "unix:///run/user/$uid/podman/podman.sock"
    } else if (os.isMacOsX()) {
        environment "DOCKER_HOST", "unix:///tmp/podman.sock"
    }
    environment "TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED", "true"
}
```

Set `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to Podman socket file depending on the operating system.

Disable Ryuk with the environment variable `TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED`.

> [Moby Ryuk](https://github.com/testcontainers/moby-ryuk) helps you to remove containers/networks/volumes/images by given filter after specified delay.

Ryuk is a technology for Docker and doesn't support Podman. See [testcontainers/moby-ryuk#23](https://github.com/testcontainers/moby-ryuk/issues/23)

Testcontainers library uses Ruyk to remove containers. Instead of relying on Ryuk to implicitly remove containers, we will explicitly remove containers with a JVM shutdown hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(container::stop));
```

### Pass the environment variables

As an alternative to configuring Testcontainers in a Gradle build script, you can pass the environment variables to Gradle.

#### Linux

```
DOCKER_HOST="unix:///run/user/$UID/podman/podman.sock" \
TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED="true" \
./gradlew clean build -i
```

#### MacOS

```
DOCKER_HOST="unix:///tmp/podman.sock" \
TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED="true" \
./gradlew clean build -i
```

### Full example

See the full example https://github.com/evgeniy-khist/podman-testcontainers

Comment: any example that podman is running inside a container

Comment: @Eugene Khyst The mentioned issue got an update. It seems like Ryuk works with Podman.

Comment: On macOS you can install [podman-mac-helper](https://podman-desktop.io/docs/migrating-from-docker/using-podman-mac-helper) instead of creating the socket by your own

Answer (score 14):

I was able to build on Evginiy's excellent answer, since Podman has improved in the time since the original answer. On Mac OS, these steps were sufficient for me and made testcontainers happy:

Edit `~/.testcontainers.properties` and add the following line

```
ryuk.container.privileged=true
```

Then run the following

```
brew install podman
podman machine init
sudo /opt/homebrew/Cellar/podman/4.0.3/bin/podman-mac-helper install
podman machine set --rootful
podman machine start
```

If you don't want to run rootful podman, ryuk needs to be disabled:

```
export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED="true"
```

Running without ryuk basically works, but lingering containers can sometimes cause problems and name collisions in automated tests. Evginiy's suggestion of a shutdown hook would resolve this, but would need code changes.

Answer (score 8):

For Linux, it definitely work even though official testcontainers documentation is not really clear about it.

```sh
# Enable socket
systemctl --user enable podman.socket --now

# Export env var expected by Testcontainers
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/${UID}/podman/podman.sock
export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true
```

Sources:

- https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-devservices-testcontainers-podman/
- https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2088#issuecomment-893404306

Answer (score 2):

An add-on to @hollycummins answer.  You can get it working without `--rootful` by setting the following environment variables (or their testcontainers properties counter part):

```
DOCKER_HOST=unix:///Users/steve/.local/share/containers/podman/machine/podman-machine-default/podman.sock`
TESTCONTAINERS_DOCKER_SOCKET_OVERRIDE=/var/run/user/501/podman/podman.sock
TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_CONTAINER_PRIVILEGED=true
```

This will mount the podman socket of the linux VM into the Ryuk container. 501 is the UID of the user `core` in the linux VM user. See `podman machine ssh`.

Comment: For me, the accepted answer with just setting DOCKER_HOST did not work (on macOS). However, setting TESTCONTAINERS_DOCKER_SOCKET_OVERRIDE did work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you running testcontainer build inside a docker container, alternatively you can start the service like this

```
podman system service -t 0 unix:///tmp/podman.sock &
```

OR

```
podman system service -t 0 tcp:127.0.0.1:19999 &
```