# testcontainers-java postgresql with podman

Tags: testcontainers

TLDR: org.testcontainers:postgresql:jar:1.18.3 seems to ignore certain settings.

---

I'm trying to use testcontainers postgresql for unit tests in my java app.  I've read a bunch of articles/questions about this, including [tc-with-podman-in-java-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71549856/testcontainers-with-podman-in-java-tests),

Back when we were allowed to use docker desktop, it worked fine.  But now I'm trying to do this with podman (I'm not attached to podman, but I have tried other things and can't get testcontainers to use them either).

From what I've read, to use podman, I have to set some things in my `~/.testcontainers.properties`.

```
docker.host=unix:///tmp/podman.sock                                                                                                                                                           
ryuk.disabled=true
testcontainers.ryuk.disabled=true
testcontainers.checks.disable=true
testcontainers.reuse.enable=true

# maybe one of these will work?
TESTCONTAINERS_REUSE_ENABLE=true
REUSE_ENABLE=true
reuse.enable=true
```

But when I do that, ryuk runs anyway, throws an exception, and exits the whole thing.  It looks to me as though [TestContainersConfiguration.loadConfiguration](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/8465795ab9067447ca8b7d3e307cadcec8de377a/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/utility/TestcontainersConfiguration.java#L358C16-L358C16) passes in `System.getenv()` as the environment, and that [RyukResourceReaper.init](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/8465795ab9067447ca8b7d3e307cadcec8de377a/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/utility/RyukResourceReaper.java#L40) doesn't look at the userProperties having ryuk being disabled, but it checks the *environment variables* for `TESTCONTAINERS_REUSE_ENABLE`.

I tried [`GenericContainer.setEnv()`](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/8465795ab9067447ca8b7d3e307cadcec8de377a/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/GenericContainer.java#L1024), but that sets the container env, it doesn't seem to affect the test for `TESTCONTAINERS_REUSE_ENABLE`.

Also, I discovered that I could put environment variables in my pom, but even that had an issue.

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                    <configuration>                                                                                                                                                       
                        <environmentVariables>                                                                                                                                                
                            <TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED>true</TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED>                                                                                                 
                            <TESTCONTAINERS_REUSE_ENABLE>true</TESTCONTAINERS_REUSE_ENABLE>                                                                                                   
                        </environmentVariables>                                                                                                                                               
                    </configuration>
```

yielded `TESTCONTAINERS_REUSE_ENABLE` of `"true"`.  Note that isn't `true`.  And with the quotes, `Boolean.parse` returns false.

What I'm doing right now is *terrible*.  I'm using reflection to make the `System.getenv()` map modifiable, and adding to it.  I'm *sure* this isn't the way it's supposed to work.

How is it supposed to work?  I'm on a mac in case it matters.

FWIW, my code (minus the hacks to set env vars) is *very* simple.  I don't think I'm doing anything crazy here.

```
        PostgreSQLContainer<?> psc = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13.10");
        psc.start();
        psc.createConnection("");
```

Comment: did `unix:///tmp/podman.sock` exists?

Answer (score 0):

Export the following env vars in your terminal

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix://$(podman machine inspect --format '{{.ConnectionInfo.PodmanSocket.Path}}')
export TESTCONTAINERS_DOCKER_SOCKET_OVERRIDE=/var/run/docker.sock
```

If in rootless mode then add

```
export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true
```

If in rootful mode then add

```
export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_PRIVILEGED=true
```